# NUnit - TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status is always "Inconclusive"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, nunit

I've noticed that NUnit's [TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/TestContext.html) is always `Inconclusive` at the end of a test run. The CurrentContext is also unaware that any assertions have taken place.

Is it possible to get the status of a test before the [TearDown]?

I was hoping to use the value during the Dispose() of my test management class to capture metrics and other data for post-test diagnosis.

Code example from a new .NET Framework 4.6.1 project that only has the NuGet packages NUnit and FluentAssertions:

```
namespace TestProject
{
    using FluentAssertions;
    using NUnit.Framework;

    [TestFixture]
    public class Class1
    {
        [Test]
        public void test1()
        {
            var a = 1;
            var b = 2;
            var c = 1;

            var context = TestContext.CurrentContext;

            a.Should().Be(c);

            Assert.AreEqual(a, c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which nuget packages do you have installed in your test project? Are you using Visual Studio test runner or a 3rd party such as Resharper?

Comment: Also, could you show us some code? Maybe some basic unit test that used to run successfully before but is now inconclusive when using FluentAssertions?

Comment: I added code., but you got me thinking and I found that Outcome is not set until the Test method is exited, and can seemingly only be accessed from a `[TearDown]` method. I can't use `[TearDown]` because of [NUnit limitations](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2574)). So I think the real issue is that I need a way to detect the test outcome from inside the test that doesn't rely on `[TearDown]`. And it sounds like the Outcome is not going to be the way to accomplish that. Does this sound correct?

Comment: I have to confess that I never needed to use the TestContext... Just out of curiosity, why do you need to use it?

Comment: BTW I added a `[TearDown]` method, `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status` is `Passed` there.

Comment: Charlie also sent in an answer and I responded there, and yes you're right - the Outcome isn't available until the end of test execution. I'm hoping to use it to only capture screenshots and logs if a failure occurs but I don't think this is a supported use case since the design of the Outcome is that it's not determined until TearDown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A test result starts out as `Inconclusive`. If the test is skipped or ignored, then the result changes, but of course it is never executed.

If it is executed, the Outcome is `Inconclusive` until the test is over. Clearly, while you are still executing the test, it is not yet finished. When teardown begins, the outcome of the test is known, so it will vary according to whether the test method itself was successful. Of course, an exception in teardown may change the result to an Error state.

Bottom line, the Outcome field is not useful while the test method itself is still running. In any case, if you are executing code in the test method, the test has not yet failed. Otherwise, you would not have continued execution!

You say you can't use TearDown but the link you provide doesn't deal with the issue of accessing the test result. Can you explain further? What exactly do you want to do after checking the test result?

Comment: Hey Charlie, thanks for the response! I am hoping to access the test result so I can capture screenshots and browser console logs on a test failure only. My misunderstanding was thinking that the change in behavior was related to FluentAssertions when actually it was when I started using a custom disposable object called TestFactory to get around sharing of fixture members between tests run in parallel (what's being discussed on that GitHub issue) instead of using a TearDown method. I think this just isn't a supported use case, right?

Comment: So maybe remove the `fluent-assertions` tag?

Comment: My bad, I hadn't gotten to it yet. Removed now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `AssertionScope` along with the `AssertionScope.Succeeded` flag. Although the intelisense on that property specifies:

> Gets a value indicating whether or not the last assertion executed through this scope succeeded.

## Example usage of `AssertionScope`

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{

    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    var c = 1;

    var context = new AssertionScope();

    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Test");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        context.FailWith(e.ToString());
    }

    var strings = context.Discard();

    Console.WriteLine(strings.StringJoin(","));

    context.Succeeded.Should().BeFalse();


    var someOtherContext = new AssertionScope();

    try
    {
        c.Should().Be(a);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        someOtherContext.FailWith(e.ToString());
    }

    var discard = someOtherContext.Discard();

    Console.WriteLine(discard.StringJoin(","));

    someOtherContext.Succeeded.Should().BeTrue();

}
```